# Configuring a Build Job with Bamboo (CI platform)

Tags: continuous-integration, bamboo

I have a Bamboo instance setup to do builds with the following config:

1. Bamboo version = 3.0.1
2. when running the build, i got the following error:

```
09-Mar-2011 08:57:50    Pulling from repository `/root/POC/PRS' to directory '/root/bamboo-ci/xml-data/build-dir/_hg-repositories-cache/d20373e808a2d0e95a604129054231a0da36ff99'
09-Mar-2011 08:57:50    pulling from /root/POC/PRAEFECTUS
09-Mar-2011 08:57:50    searching for changes
09-Mar-2011 08:57:50    no changes found
09-Mar-2011 08:57:50    Copying repository from cache directory to source directory...
09-Mar-2011 08:57:50    Creating empty repository in directory '/root/bamboo-ci/xml-data/build-dir/PRQA-PRQAKEY-JOB1'
09-Mar-2011 08:57:50    Pulling from repository `/root/bamboo-ci/xml-data/build-dir/_hg-repositories-cache/d20373e808a2d0e95a604129054231a0da36ff99' to directory '/root/bamboo-ci/xml-data/build-dir/PRQA-PRQAKEY-JOB1'
09-Mar-2011 08:57:51    pulling from /root/bamboo-ci/xml-data/build-dir/_hg-repositories-cache/d20373e808a2d0e95a604129054231a0da36ff99
09-Mar-2011 08:57:51    requesting all changes
09-Mar-2011 08:57:51    adding changesets
09-Mar-2011 08:57:51    adding manifests
09-Mar-2011 08:57:51    adding file changes
09-Mar-2011 08:57:51    added 1 changesets with 810 changes to 810 files
09-Mar-2011 08:57:51    (run 'hg update' to get a working copy)
09-Mar-2011 08:57:52    810 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
09-Mar-2011 08:57:52    Updated source code to revision: cc40b2d9c09ea747529887dd8db9319f53c5db4e
09-Mar-2011 08:57:52    Executing build PRQA-PRQAKEY-JOB1-2
09-Mar-2011 08:57:52    Running pre-build action: Build Number Stamper
09-Mar-2011 08:57:52    Running pre-build action: Clover Grails PreBuild Action
09-Mar-2011 08:57:52    Running pre-build action: VCS Version Collector
09-Mar-2011 08:57:52    Running pre-build action: Repository Isolation Enabler Action
09-Mar-2011 08:57:52    Running pre-build action: Maven Settings Prebuild Action
09-Mar-2011 08:57:52    Building started with ScriptBuilder
09-Mar-2011 08:57:52    
Starting to build 'PRAEFECTUS-QA - PRQA-PLAN - Default Job'
... running command line: /bin/sh Makefile
... in : /root/bamboo-ci/xml-data/build-dir/PRQA-PRQAKEY-JOB1
09-Mar-2011 08:57:52    Makefile: 10: PYTHON: not found
```

but if we look at the folder listed in the error, the Makefile is there

```
root@bambooserver:~/bamboo-ci/xml-data/build-dir/PRQA-PRQAKEY-JOB1# ls -l
total 104
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   45 2011-03-09 08:57 AUTHORS
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2011-03-09 08:57 bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  138 2011-03-09 08:57 build-number.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  120 2011-03-09 08:57 CHANGES
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 9703 2011-03-09 08:57 ez_setup.py
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2011-03-09 08:57 images
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2011-03-09 08:57 init.d
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 2011-03-09 08:57 iped
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2011-03-09 08:57 logrotate.d
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  932 2011-03-09 08:57 Makefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  175 2011-03-09 08:57 MANIFEST.in
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2011-03-09 08:57 nbproject
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1109 2011-03-09 08:57 NEWS
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 2011-03-09 08:57 prs
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 2011-03-09 08:57 rpa
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2011-03-09 08:57 sbin
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 2011-03-09 08:57 scripts
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   81 2011-03-09 08:57 setup.cfg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2796 2011-03-09 08:57 setup.py
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2011-03-09 08:57 src
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 2011-03-09 08:57 test
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 2011-03-09 08:57 tests
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  501 2011-03-09 08:57 TODO
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    6 2011-03-09 08:57 VERSION
root@bambooserver:~/bamboo-ci/xml-data/build-dir/PRQA-PRQAKEY-JOB1#
```

any tips on how to setup a Job in Bamboo ? i am using Mercurial and project is in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see you've used a ScriptBuilder which is dedicated to running a shell script while you probably need a builder that runs a command

```
make
```

What you need to do is:

- go to Administration / Server Capabilities
- in "Add Capability" select: Capability Type: Builder, Type: Command, Builder Label: Make, Path: enter the full path to your make utility (ie. /usr/bin/make)
- now navigate to your plan configuration and change the builder to "Make"

After those changes your build should be working fine.

PS.
In case of future problems you should try reporting the problem on Atlassian's support site (http://support.atlassian.com)

Disclaimer: yes I work for Atlassian

Comment: somehow i get faster response here :) but i will post it on the forums, as i am a trial customer. But thank you for your help.

Comment: FYI, I'm also a trial customer, and I have found good response also by Atlassian support.